# Limit the number of check boxes selected

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, checkbox, jcheckbox

I am writing a Java App that has multiple items available to test.
However -- due to HW limitations, I can only test 4 devices in parallel.
I was wondering -- in genera -- how can I get Java to limit the number of selected items to only four (no matter which ones are picked)?
I am reading through the Java docs and I can't seem to find the answer to that.

I am fairly new to Java -- so please forgive my ignorance.
I just need a clue as to where/how to start.

How do I limit the number of check boxes selected in Java?

Comment: What is your code? What Java libraries are you using? Are you using Swing? GWT? Pure AWT? Something else? Show us the code where you create the check boxes, and your attempt at (or the pseudocode/logic for) limiting the number being checked.

Comment: Can I just add the class file where I created the check boxes?

Comment: Oh -- sorry -- I am using swing

Comment: Just copy-paste the code where you create the check boxes and any handlers (eg ClickHandler) that you attached to them.

Comment: I'd probably represent this as 2 lists with D'n'D.  After four 'HW devices' are dragged from the 'system' list to the 'test' list, ignore further drag events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Swing, start with creating an array of JCheckBox[] and fill it with checkboxes. Create then ChangeListener and global variable with amount of checked checkboxes. Add this listener to all of checkboxes. In ChangeListener's `stateChanged()` method increase or decrease your global variable by 1. If variable reach four, disable all of checkboxes with setEnabled(false) except those which are checked. When you'll decrease your variable from 4 to 3, set them to enabled.

This is good example about ChangeListener:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Event/CheckBoxItemListener.htm

Comment: I put in some code: if (asus_prime_1.isSelected()) {JoptionPaneshowMessageDialog(null, "Asus Prime selected"); }  -- whne I tried to run my app and I clicked on asus_prime_1, nothing happened.  I am totally lost...

Answer (score 3):

I would create a global variable that can hold the count of devices started.

When a check box is clicked, in it's event handler, add to the variable if it was checked and subtract if it was unchecked.

Of course you would check before you add that the value was less than 5 (0 - 4) before allowing another to be checked.

Comment: Thanks!  I have no idea why I didn't think of that.  SO let me ask this question: Is the event handler a boolean that returns a one or zero??

Comment: Well the event handler will probably be a void or null type. It has been years since I worked in Java. The point here is that you are watching for clicks. I know java has an addhandler which means you could easily assign  the same handler method to each and every check box. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/EventHandler.html

Comment: Event handler is the code you attach to the click event. So that code could do three things (you choose): 1) if 4 is reached disable other unchecked boxes to disallow more checking; 2) if it exists, disable "run tests" button if more that 4 boxes are checked 3) if at the moment of a click there are 5 checked, then deselect the current box programatically). I should choose the second way. It's more clear.

Comment: seudo-code: onclick(...) { count checked boxes; buttonRunTests.setEnabled(count <= 4); };

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of all of your checkboxes. Add a call to the following check in the stateChanged() in the listener:

- Loop through and query the states of all the checkboxes and count how many are checked.
- If the number of checked boxes is equal to or greater than 4, then loop through all checkboxes again and disable all checkboxes that were unchecked.
- Else if the number of checked boxes is less than 4, enable all checkboxes.

Incrementing / decrementing a global count on the number of checkboxes might seem more slightly more efficient, but the gain is negligible when dealing with UIs. I would say it's better to code defensively to avoid corner cases and bugs from trying to keep track of state information rather than just polling it.

For defensive programming, you want to also validate the input from the UI to check that the number of checked boxes is less than or equal to 4.